# No se ejecuta sentencia mysql en funcion php

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos soy nuevo en php.. Tengo una sentencia mysql q no se me sentencia en una funcion php, la ejecuto en mysql y si me ejecuta en la funcion no. Ademas los datos llegan a la funcion y todo lo unico q no me ejecuta es la semtencia de mysql

```
function RegistrarUsuario($smallnameusuario,$contraseñausuario)
{
    $mensaje = "";

    if(isset($smallnameusuario,$contraseñausuario))
    {

        $tipoUsuario = 1;
        //$currDate = getDate(); // generas un llamado al metodo

        $fecharegistro = date("Y-m-d");

        $idpersona = ObtenerUltimaPersona();
        $eliminadologico = 1;

        echo "Usuario: ".$smallnameusuario.", ";
        echo "Contraseña: ".$contraseñausuario.", ";
        echo "Tipo: ".$tipoUsuario.", ";
        echo "Fecha: ".$fecharegistro.", ";
        echo "ID Persona: ".$idpersona.", ";
        echo "Eliminado logico: ".$eliminadologico.". ";


        $query2 = "INSERT INTO registro(idpersona, idtipousuario, nombreusuario, contraseña, fecharegistro, eliminadologicor) VALUES ('".$idpersona."','".$tipoUsuario."','".$smallnameusuario."','".$contraseñausuario."','".$fecharegistro."','".$eliminadologico."')";

    $con2 = conexionBD();
    $accion2 = mysqli_query($con2,$query2);

    if($accion2)
    {
        $mensaje= "Correcto";
    }else
    {
        $mensaje= "No se pudo ejecutar la acción";

    }



    }else
    {
        $mensaje = "Los datos no fueron recibidos correctamente";
    }


    echo $mensaje;
    return $mensaje;
}
```

Los echos q estan ahi los puse para constantar que si estaba entrando a la funcion. el idpersona es obtenido con otra funcion que si ejecuta.

Comment: ¿Qué hace el código, imprime este mensaje: `No se pudo ejecutar la acción`?  Agrégale esto para ver si da alguna descripción del error: `$mensaje= "No se pudo ejecutar la acción. Ocurrió el error: ".mysqli_error($con2);`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near    eso es lo q me sale

Comment: Parece que `$query2` tiene un error de sintaxis. ¿Puedes imprimirla con `echo $query2;` para ver cómo se está creando la consulta?

Comment: INSERT INTO registro(idpersona, idtipousuario, nombreusuario, contraseña, fecharegistro, eliminadologicor) VALUES ('15','1','a','a','2018-06-05','1')  esto es lo q sale

Comment: Es una pena que no hayas puesto el mensaje de error completo, pues en tu comentario te quedaste en `your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ...` Lo más relevante del mensaje es lo que viene después de la palabra **near**. La consulta tiene algunos errores, aunque a veces funciona, conviene que, los valores que sean de tipo numérico en la base de datos **no vayan encerrados entre comillas**. Por ejemplo: `INSERT INTO registro(idpersona...) VALUES (15,...)` si `idpersona`  es de tipo numérico, el `15` debería ir sin `' '` Y así con todas las otras...

Comment: ... columnas que sean de un tipo numérico. Pero como te decía, en muchos casos funciona. Lo más importante es que revises si realmente la tabla se llama así: `registro` y si los nombres de columna están escritos correctamente: `idpersona, idtipousuario, nombreusuario, contraseña, fecharegistro, eliminadologicor`... compáralo en la base de datos misma. Por cierto, no es recomendable usar `ñ` o caracteres acentuados en nombres de tablas o columnas.

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto de php y gracias con eso solucione mi problema

Comment: Me alegro... pero... he dicho muchas cosas, **¿con qué lo solucionaste?**, ¿cuál era el error, una columna o algo mal escrito?

Comment: Le saque la comilla a los valores numerico y tbn modifique el campo contraseña para por contrasena, como tu dices lo de los valores numericos debe funcioner por eso creo que el error estaba en los caracter ñ

Comment: Bien. Cuando pueda escribiré una respuesta implementando consultas preparadas, ya que actualmente tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias, estare atento

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un código implementando consultas preparadas.

He comentado las partes más importantes, explicando el modo de construir la consulta (`A`)  y de pasarle los parámetros (`B`).

Me he permitido usar variables más descriptivas, que ayuden a leer/entender el código. Nunca se recomienda usar variables del tipo `$con2, query2...`. Cuando el programa crezca y veas esas variables no tendrás ni idea de lo que hacen.

He usado una convención de nombres de variables en inglés, por ser mucho más fácil y práctica, aunque se programe en español. Además, te ayudará a no caer en la tentación de escribir nombres de variables con `ñ` o con acentos... En muchos sitios recomiendan usar el inglés por ser más universal. Esto es cuestión de gustos.

El código quedaría más o menos así:

```
function RegistrarUsuario($usrSmallName,$usrPass)
{
    $mensaje = "";

    if(isset($usrSmallName,$usrPass))
    {
        $usrType = 1;
        //$currDate = getDate(); // generas un llamado al metodo
        $usrDate = date("Y-m-d");
        $usrID = ObtenerUltimaPersona();
        $usrDelete = 1;
        echo "Usuario: ".$usrSmallName.", ";
        echo "Contraseña: ".$usrPass.", ";
        echo "Tipo: ".$usrType.", ";
        echo "Fecha: ".$usrDate.", ";
        echo "ID Persona: ".$usrID.", ";
        echo "Eliminado logico: ".$usrDelete.". ";

        /*
            *(A) 1er paso para consultas preparadas
            *En vez de pasar los datos directamente a la consulta
            *se usan marcadores de posición ?
            *y los valores en sí son pasados por el método mysqli_stmt_bind_param
            *Esto evita que se cuele código malicioso o manipulado
        */
        $usrInsert = "INSERT INTO registro(idpersona, idtipousuario, nombreusuario, contrasena, fecharegistro, eliminadologicor)
                               VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $con = conexionBD();
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $usrInsert))
        {
            /* 
                *(B) como se dijo en (A)
                *aquí pasamos cada valor al statement
                *Hay que tener en cuenta que:
                * - las letras "iisssi" corresponden el tipo de dato de cada valor (i)nteger, (s)tring
                * - cada tipo de dato debe ir en el orden en que está cada columna en $usrInsert
                * - cada variable debe pasarse en el orden respectivo a cada columna en $usrInsert
                * - en $usrInsert debe haber tantos marcadores de posicion ? como columnas
            */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iisssi", $usrSmallName,$usrPass,$usrType,$usrDate,$usrID,$usrDelete);
            /* ejecutar la consulta */
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $mensaje="Correcto. Se insertaron ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)." registros";
        }else
        {
            $mensaje= "No se pudo ejecutar la acción. Ocurrió el error: ".mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }else
    {
        $mensaje = "Los datos no fueron recibidos correctamente";
    }
    echo $mensaje;
    return $mensaje;
}
```